# Is their any way to eliminate two backward slash to one in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I came to a scenario while using eclipse, in which if i use **two back slash** in below mention function.

```
 "private Keywords(){
    try{
    OR=new Properties();
    FileInputStream fs=new   FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"**\\src\\com\\config\\OR.properties"**);
    OR.load(fs);
    "
```

this function works  but if I use **single slash** it won't work . Is their way that i would be able to use single backward slash only while giving a source path..

Comment: Why not use forward slashes? Java is fully able to deal with that, even on Windows systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with Eclipse.

You need to escape back-slashes in `String`s, as they are themselves an escape character.

What you can eventually use to somewhat "shorten" your code is the system property `System.getProperty("file.separator")`, then assign it to some constant and use that reference instead.

But that's close to cosmetics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 2 backslashes as a single variable say,

```
String separator = "\\";

String file_path = "src"+separator +"com"+separator +"config"+separator +"OR.properties";

System.out.println("File Path is :: " + file_path);
```

Or as Mena Suggested, you can use:

```
String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it straight with your String literals

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html